# How to start a new process in an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, windows, process

The default browser on our web servers is IE. We have a requirement to launch an instance of Chrome on a button click on one of our web apps.

I have written an asp.net test app to try to achieve the above. In the test app I start a process on a button click on the server side to launch Chrome, but the Chrome window does not appear. The process seems to start fine as I get the the process ID and HasExited property is false. However, nothing comes up on screen and I don't seem to be able to find the process in the list of processes.

I know that in a web app, a process starts in the context of the asp.net worker process and that it does not have access to the desktop and has restricted permissions. So I gave the IIS Admin Service process permission to interact with desktop on my local machine (via Processes window). Also, in the code I tried starting the process using my own user account which has admin access to the local machine but still could not get the Chrome window to appear on screen.

My server side code is as follows:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
    Arguments = "http://www.msn.com",
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = true
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "secure password",
    Domain = "domain"
};
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = psi
};
var result = process.Start(); // result is true
int processId = process.Id; // processId is valid
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have a problem in your requirements. You definitely don't want to start a web browser on the server as a child of the IIS process. Because that's what happens when you start a process from ASP.NET. This means that the process will run on the invisible desktop named "session 0". It will not be accessible by users logged in to the server, and definitely not start on the client's machine. If a web application could start arbitrary executables on a client, that'd be a huge security issue. So please translate your requirements _"I need to start a web browser"_ to what you actually need.

Comment: Hi  CodeCaster, Thanks for your very useful info. I did not know about the session  0 desktop. But I don't know what you mean by translating my requirement. My requirement is to be able to launch Chrome on a button click. So what solution would you propose for that?

Comment: Launch Chrome **where**? If you launch it from ASP.NET, it will run, invisible, on the server. Why would you want to do that? And if you want to start it on the client, you **cannot do that**. Again, why would you want to do that?

Comment: CodeCaster, the reason is rather long to explain. As I said, our default browser is IE and we cannot change that. We are using some new D365 apps for part of our business. Some parts of these apps have issues running on IE, so our only solution for now is to launch Chrome to access those parts. As to where to launch, it will be on both clients and servers. You have asked me why we want to do it, but have not suggested an alternative way to do it. One other way is to launch Chrome on the client side but it comes up with an ActiveX dialog box, which I don't think our IT team likes to disable.

Comment: I haven't given you any workarounds, because there aren't any. You cannot start arbitrary processes on the client side, without browser plugins (such as ActiveX controls, which you definitely don't want to use). If you need a certain action to launch Chrome on your company network, you need to talk with your IT team about. `Process.Start()` launches a process on the web server.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster. Understood